# Specify Login page in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

how to specify a login page? I`m getting such error while trying to access some page:

> Error: Login is required, but no valid login page has been specified for the site (sitename).

My webconfig contains such records:

```
<sites>
  <site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="2MB" registryCacheSize="3MB" viewStateCacheSize="200KB" xslCacheSize="5MB" disableBrowserCaching="true" />
  <site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" />
  <site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx" />
  <site name="service" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service" />
  <site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
  <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" />
  <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" loginPage="/shop/account/login"/>
  <site name="scheduler" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
  <site name="system" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
  <site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
</sites>
```

I have tried to set path to the login page in website as a loginPage attribute, but it doesn`t work

Comment: Is this a page (/shop/account/login) in Sitecore? Because it must point to a physical file or a page in a site that does NOT require login, and if your website site requires login that will not work.

Comment: Trayek, yes, it is. For now i have no idea why it doesn`t work. Maybe paths are set incorrect.. But URL  http://sitename/shop/account/login works fine

Comment: Is there any other site in sitedefination.config file or you are using only website site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error only happens in the following three cases:

1. The site's `loginPage` attribute is missing or empty.
2. You're currently in the "edit" or "preview" mode **AND** the `shell` site is undefined or its `loginPage` is undefined or empty.
3. `Sitecore.Context.Site` is `null`.

To troubleshoot this, you can try the following:

1. Determine which `<site>` the page you're accessing belongs to. Are you 100% sure it's the `<site name="website">`?
2. Verify that the `loginPage` attribute is not empty for that site.
3. Open the page where you're getting the error in the "normal" mode by adding `?sc_mode=normal` in the query string.
4. In the file system, go to every folder that corresponds to the URL path of your page. Look for a ***site.config*** file and if you find one, see what sites are defined there. `loginPage` may be missing from such a site definition, and if Sitecore finds one, it is not going to look at the main `<sites>` section in the ***Web.config***.
5. Try adding `?sc_site=website` to your query string in order to enforce the `Sitecore.Context.Site` to point to the right `<site>` definition.

Comment: thank you a lot!!! I`ve spent so much time for this... And without you i would not be able to fix it. I`ve tried to acess directly "website" definition adding ?sc_site=website, and found out that it works corect. After this i`ve found another we config file with another site definition, added a loginPage url to it.. And it helped! You are awesome!

Comment: @user1561325 I am happy I could help :)